# Trying comparing strings in C

Tags: c, string, strcmp

I'm trying compare two strings with the function *srtcmp* but do not get the result i want. The program is coded in C and should print the name of the user only if is older and male. Any case, only else instructions are executed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

char name[20], sex[15];
int age;

printf("\n Your name here: "); fgets(name, 21, stdin);
printf(" Your sex here: "); fgets(sex, 16, stdin);
printf(" You age here: "); scanf("%i", &age);

if(strcmp(sex, "male")==0 && age>=18) {
    printf("\n %s you are old.\n\n", name);     
}

else {
    printf("\n You are not old.\n\n");
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You say you're not getting the result you want, but you haven't specified what inputs you're giving to your program and what it actually outputs.  Note that `fgets` normally includes a trailing newline from the input. Also, you're lying to `fgets` about how big your buffers are.  It's fine to tell give `fgets` buffer sizes smaller than they actually are, but you're doing the opposite.

Comment: I'd suggest you perform some basic debugging by printing out the `name` to see what it is.

Comment: `fgets()` keeps a newline at the end of the data it reads; your string `"male"` does not have a newline at the end.  So, the strings never compare equal.